# How Do I Fix This Broken Switch?

Tags: dimmer-switch

What's the simplest path for me to fix this?  Is it possible for me to order a new "cap" somehow or do I need to replace the whole switch plate?

Thanks in advance!

[image: Photo of switch]

Answer (score 3):

Google search:

[Split Replacement Knob Lutron](https://www.google.com/search?q=Split%20Replacement%20Knob%20Lutron&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiM3uvA2rfLAhViyYMKHa8oA2wQ_AUICCgC&biw=1024&bih=639) (aka Skylark)

Comment: It appears to be model # 28051027.

Comment: Fantastic find, going above and beyond on that answer!  And to take nothing away from that... With shipping/handling, it may be wiser to put the money toward a newer, more stylish and less fragile dimmer, maybe an electronic one that supports features you might desire.

Comment: My preference are Decora style with the tiny slider switch on the side. There's no button that can fall off those.

Answer (score 1):

Take your photo to home depot.  They'll show you the switch with the cap.  Then, in home depot, because it has wifi, using the brand and model to find just the cap online. Either buy the switch there or order the cap online.